# Unknown equipment on the back of some runabouts

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, spaceship, object-identification

The runabouts in Deep Space Nine sometimes have additional equipment on their backs; this is a screenshot from S02E15 (Paradise), showing the Orinoco in the background with the unknown equipment & the Rio Grande in the foreground with a clean configuration:[image: Screenshot from Paradise]

What is the equipment & why is it only sometimes present?

Comment: More info than anyone could sensibly need here - ["Runabouts With Rollbars"](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/rollbar.htm)

Comment: Even includes the same shot from Paradise I posted; nicely done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Star Trek Encyclopedia](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia) makes mention of a "roll bar" added to the USS **Ganges** runabout model. This was apparently an *additional sensor array*. We can reasonably assume that the same feature on the Orinoco was intended for the same use.

From an out-of-universe perspective it was simply so that viewers would know, at a glance, which of the (otherwise identical) runabouts they were looking at.

[image: Capture of USS Ganges article in Star Trek Encyclopedia]

> In that episode, it sported a "roll bar" that contained sensor
>   equipment. From a visual-effects standpoint, the purpose of the roll
>   bar was to make it easier to tell the Ganges from the Yangtze Kiang
>   in that episode's chase sequence.

Comment: They're swappable for mission-specific requirements. Weapons modules are also available, if I remember right.

Comment: @pleurocoelus - I've seen that, but only on fan-sites. Can you provide some evidence?

Comment: Thus the "if I remember right" part. I believe it was in the DS9 Technical Manual, which a friend of mine had, but that was years ago that I read it.

Comment: @pleurocoelus - The swappable components mention in the DS9 Technical Manual relate to the crew compartment in the back. There are a range of different modules that can simply be slid into place; lab modules, power generators and sensor packages. Those aren't the rollbar on the top, they're mounted inside the runabout itself.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, it was years ago... the mind is the first to go.